# How to identify the format of the given date in perl

Tags: perl, date

I have started learning perl and I am having on some problem. where there may be varity of dates in different formats can be as input. And I have to sort those dates in chronological order.
What I planned is to convert each date in single date format and store it in hash as date in common format (as key) and and date in origin given format (as value). Now run sort on that hash and print dates with original formats (values in hash) in output.

But how to do it? I found one way to convert date with one format in another format as below.

```
use Time::Piece;

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime('Sep 12 00:00:00 2012', '%b %e %T %Y');
print $dt->strftime('%d-%m-%Y');
```

But in this case I have to be aware of what is the format of the date being inputted. Which I don't know at the time of execution because it depends on the users. So is there is any method to compare and decide that which format is of this date?

```
#This is my input file
#only four formats will be there in input dates. (MM/DD/YY,
#DD-MM-YYYY, MMM-DD-YY or DD-MMM-YYYY)

10/01/92
18-07-1984
Oct-20-17
04-Jan-2004  

#This is what I want in output
18-07-1984
10/01/92
04-Jan-2004
Oct-20-17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Time::Piece->strptime()` will `die()` if you give it a date string that can't be parsed using the given format. But we can use `eval` to get around that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my @dates = qw[
  10/01/92
  18-07-1984
  Oct-20-17
  04-Jan-2004
];

my @fmts = qw[
  %m/%d/%y
  %d-%m-%Y
  %b-%d-%y
  %d-%b-%Y
];

foreach (@dates) {
  my $tp;

  for my $fmt (@fmts) {
    eval { $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($_, $fmt) };
    last unless $@;
  }
  say $tp;
}
```

In this code, we work our way through a list of formats until we find one that doesn't `die()`.

That will give you a date in a Time::Piece object that you can store somewhere. Sorting those objects is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

**Note:** You need to be really sure that your users will only be using dates in those four formats. In general, this problem is insoluble because you might have someone who inputs 07/09/2000 to mean 7th September 2000 (dd/mm dates are far more common than mm/dd ones outside of the US).

Comment: The sorting strongly smells of one Mr Schwartz. :)

Comment: @simbabque I was certainly thinking along those lines.

Comment: Perhaps the [`DateTime::Format::Natural`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Natural/lib/DateTime/Format/Natural.pm) module might also be an alternative. I haven't used it myself but they advertise that all the formats given [here](http://search.cpan.org/~schubiger/DateTime-Format-Natural-1.05/lib/DateTime/Format/Natural/Lang/EN.pm) would work. If that's true then it's incredibly cool!

Comment: @PerlDuck: Feel free to try it, but I suspect that its `format` config option means that it couldn't parse both `MM/DD/YY` and `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Comment: FYI: I tried DT:F:N with the given dates. It yielded `10.01.2092` (wrong), `18.07.1984` (correct), `'Oct-20-17' does not parse` (?), `04.01.2004` (correct) (all in `%d.%m.%Y`). So for the current input data it does its job roughly half the time. I'd stick with your solution :-).